# How to dual boot Chrome OS and Windows on a legacy BIOS

Tags: windows, multi-boot, chromium, google-chrome-os

I have been try to find a way to dual boot chrome OS and windows 10 since a month now but I am unable to find a solution for it.

I want to install Chrome OS on my hard drive with Windows 10.

I have made partitions but I couldn't find a way to install .bin Cloudready file or .iso chromium OS file to the partition.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: see more:: https://lifehacker.com/turn-your-old-laptop-into-a-chromebook-with-cloudready-1740556796

Comment: @Biswa The article is not for dual booting

Comment: Why don't you make your bios as UEFI (and GPT file system) and dual boot with cloudready?

Comment: @biswa My motherboard does not support UEFI

Comment: @biswa I have Asus P5KPL AM motherboard. Can I change bios to UEFI?

Comment: May be not. There is no UEFI in specs. See this:: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5KPLAM/specifications/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using booting from a usb you could use this to install the latest version of chromium os. Use the [special builds](http://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/index.php?dir=special).They have extra drivers to support as many devices as possible. It's not perfect but it works pretty well.

Comment: I have usb 2.0 so I am not satisfied with the performance

Comment: You could try installing it in a virtual machine.